# jQueryUI resizable only working vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I am using the jQueryUI `.resizable()` function to allow some

elements to be re-sized.  I want them to be resizable horizontally and vertically.  For some reason, I can only resize the left

(blue) element vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ka5V/12/show/#00ACEB

Any idea why?

Comment: I see your call in the fiddle, but what are the other files that take part in this beside the obvious jquery ones?

Comment: It's a small backbone.js app that creates the interactive interface of choosing/adding new colors into the series of `<li>`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert of backbone, If I understand correctly the problem is because you dynamically add elements to the DOM.
The dynamically added elements doesn't inherits the plugin previously set.

I think the are two ways:

1. set the resizable when you dynamically add your LI element to the DOM in your backbone app.js (I can't try it)
2. use the [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin to hook any DOM UL-LI modification and attach the resizable feature

Solution 2:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul#colors li').resizable();
  $('ul#colors li').livequery(function () {
      $(this).resizable();
  });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rVh3g/3/

I saw that resizing is not too correct, I think is something in you css, but now I can't investigate more...

Comment: line 38 of views/app.js `$(window).resize(_.bind(this.layout, this));` was causing my issue, but your answer will help me going forwards as well.  Thanks =]